# call to undefined function sqlite_libversion()

Tags: php, sqlite

I really can't se why i get this error, i have

```
extension=php_sqlite.dll
extension=php_sqlite3.dll
```

I am working with wamp with php version 5.4.3

I get the folowing error
Call to undefined function sqlite_libversion()

I have the code

```
 echo sqlite_libversion();
```

I've tried other forums and threads but all of them isa about forgetting to enable the modules, why do I still have the problem?

Comment: Does any sqlite function work? Is the module enabled according to `phpinfo()`?

Comment: Yes it's enabled accordning to phpinfo, this is my first try at working with sqlite and i've tried the function sqlite_open aswell, and it does not work.

Comment: OK, did not understand how to accept answers that's qy my rate was 0%, thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 8):

The method you seem to be looking for in Sqlite3 is:

`<?php print_r(SQLite3::version()); ?>`

Which should return:

`Array
(
    [versionString] => 3.5.9
    [versionNumber] => 3005009
)`

As per documentation at http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.version.php.

Answer (score 4):

This function is part of the (old) SQLite 2 extension, which isn't supported on PHP 5.4 - you'll only have SQLite3 with it.